# click link in htmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

in htmlunit when I do something like this:

if myLink is a link ref to a file to download (when i click the link it downloads a file into my hard drive.)

```
InputStream is= myLink.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

then the value of is will be the content of the file or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The [`click()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement.html#click%28%29) method states

> Simulates clicking on this element, returning the page in the window
>   that has the focus after the element has been clicked. Note that the
>   returned page may or may not be the same as the original page,
>   depending on the type of element being clicked, the presence of
>   JavaScript action listeners, etc.

So if your link is a basic anchor without any redirection through `javascript`, you'll get a `Page` object representing the content returned by following the link. Calling

```
getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

on that `Page` object will therefore return the response content as an input stream. This `InputStream` can also be anything: some file content, HTML, JSON, ie. whatever the server returns in the HTTP response for the HTTP request you send when clicking the link.